# Is it valid to create a static Regex object to be used by all threads in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

I need to know if it's safe to create a static Regex object like this:

```
public static Regex s_Regex_ExtractEmails = new Regex(@"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\b");
```

And call it statically from ASP.NET threads like this:

```
s_Regex_ExtractEmails.Matches("my email is mail@email.com")
```

Would this cause any problems?

I am doing this basically as an optimization so that the Regex object can be precompiled and reused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Regex instance thread safe for matches in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129287/is-regex-instance-thread-safe-for-matches-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, `Regex` objects are thread-safe. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx):

> The Regex class is immutable
>   (read-only) and is inherently thread
>   safe. Regex objects can be created on
>   any thread and shared between threads.

You might want to consider using `RegexOptions.Compiled` too - although don't *assume* it'll help performance; measure!

Comment: **Warning** : result objects (`Match` and `MatchCollection`) returned by Regex should be used on a single thread. [See doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h453d2h.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I used a static Regex in a web app and it turned out to be a bottleneck as all requests used the same single instance.

I rewrote the function so a new Regex was created for each call and problem solved.

The app may have run faster at low  usage levels but at very high levels of usage it didn't scale well.

Answer (score 2):

Not only safe, it is recommended to use it like this when you can. This approach will improve the performance of your application.