# Is Regex instance thread safe for matches in C#

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

I have this regex which I am using in a `Parallel.ForEach<string>`. Is it safe?

```
Regex reg = new Regex(SomeRegexStringWith2Groups);
Parallel.ForEach<string>(MyStrings.ToArray(), (str) =>
{
    foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(str)) //is this safe?
        lock (dict) if (!dict.ContainsKey(match.Groups[1].Value))
            dict.Add(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
});
```

Comment: The [Regex Class Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) says "The Regex class is immutable (read-only) and thread safe. *Regex objects can be created on any thread and shared between threads.*" As I cannot find anything *contrary* in the Match documentation ..

Comment: You'll probably want to switch to using a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: I would recommend  synchronizing the data source as well to eliminate the possibility of reading stale data.

Comment: Wait, doesn't ToArray return an array? In that case it wouldn't matter, right? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`Regex` objects are read-only, and therefore are thread safe.  It's their returns, the `Match` objects that could potentially cause problems.  [MSDN confirms this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h453d2h.aspx):

> The Regex class itself is thread safe and immutable (read-only). That is, Regex objects can be created on any thread and shared between threads; *matching methods can be called from any thread and never alter any global state.*
>
> However, *result objects (Match and MatchCollection) returned by Regex should be used on a single thread ..*

I'd be concerned about how your Match collection is being generated in a way that might be concurrent, which could cause the collection to act kinda weird.  Some Match implementations use delayed evaluation, which could cause some crazy behavior in that `foreach` loop.  I would probably collect all the Matches and then evaluate them later, both to be safe and to get consistent performance.

Comment: In the example posted, each `Matches` is executed and consumed by a single thread (within the Parallel.ForEach callback). It is only the `Regex` and `dict` (which is another issue), objects that cross threads ..

Comment: @pst Right, but don't its returns basically depend on whatever thread happens to be active and evaluating at the time?  You could get a couple matches from thread 1, then all of a sudden get a few from thread 2, then potentially go to thread 4 before finally seeing something else from thread 1.  Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Every callback executed in Parallels.ForEach will execute within a specific thread - since the `Match` object evaluation is forced with the `foreach` then it will be consumed by that thread (e.g. it is not being stored externally and consumed later). Thankfully since Strings are immutable (except in very rare cases of people doing some icky unsafe magic) we do not have to worry about the input so the *different* Match objects can safely have "interleaved iteration" among the *different* threads, per the docs, so long as a particular Match object is only used on a single thread (as it is).

Comment: However, this still leaves the *big* issue of `dict` (some global mutable `IDictionary` object, presumably) being mutated by multiple threads. Even if the particular Dictionary implementation did synchronize individual methods, the ContainsKey/Add pair is still not atomic. Ooops!

Comment: There, the `dict` problem is out of the way. I saw it after I posted this question.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler The last update does not fix the Dictionary issue. A *single* lock must be over *both* the operations. Otherwise they will not be atomic with respect to each other can `Add` could throw an exception. (Also, I do not know what powers of UB might exist if the if `ContainsKey` is not synchronized, even individually with a separate lock - don't play with thread fire. It's invisible until your pretty code burns up in a client environment.)

Comment: @pst Yeah, for sure.  Checking the comments on the question to boot, I'm still thinking that the safest way to do it would probably be to collect all the `Match`es up front and check the dict (with the constraint that it should be a `ConcurrentDictionary`) for its matches after harvesting information from all the threads.  That should handle the stale data issue and the multiple thread mutation problem unless I'm missing something.  Check my thinking?

Comment: @YYY I believe it is safe to do it the way in the post - assuming `dict` is updated in a thread-safe way. Once again, we have the Microsoft docs, as linked which claim Regex is thread-safe and Match/MatchCollection [iteration] is not (but that's okay because each Match is only used on a single thread), and [the guarantee of] string immutability ..

Comment: Even if I would use a concurrent dictionary, I would still have to lock it to prevent duplicates, right? So that would be pointless, right? Or are there other advantages?